# Mysql sql row to column

Tags: php, mysql

Now I have 2 tables

```
STUDENT:  

STUDENT_ID |  STUDENT_NAME | COURSE_ID  
1000       |  Anson        |     1  
1001       |  Jnson        |     1  
1002       |  Andy         |     2  
1003       |  Alex         |     3
```

COURSE:

```
COUSE_ID  |  COURSE_NAME    
1         |   P5A  
2         |   P5B  
3         |   P5C
```

Now I would like to produce the result to show the students name in each class

Idea result:

```
P5A      P5B    P5C
Anson    Andy   Alex
Jason
```

what should I do, I am using php + mysql to build web system

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from course c left join student s on c.course_id = s.course_id
order by c.course_name, c.course_id
```

Enumerate the result set. Each time course_id changes, start a new section.

Comment: But when I print it out in PHP, how do I each row print P5A, P5B, P5C student corresponding?